# How can I evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4 + x^2} + x}{x^2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> How can I evaluate the following limit

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4 + x^2} + x}{x^2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}?
$$

---

When I divided by $x^2$ the numerator and the denominator it gives me $\infty$. Am I right?

Comment: Note that:
$$0\leqslant|x|+x\lt\sqrt{4+x^2}+x\lt\sqrt{4+4|x|+x^2}+x=2+|x|+x\leqslant2(|x|+1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

divide both the numerator and the denominator by $x$ and you get: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4 + x^2} + x}{x^2 \sin (\frac{1}{x})}= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac4{x^2} + 1} + 1}{x \sin (\frac{1}{x})} $$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)=1$ is very known limit and it is obvious that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac4{x^2} + 1} + 1=\sqrt{1} + 1=2$

hence you have \begin{equation*} \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4 + x^2} + x}{x^2 \sin (\frac{1}{x})} =\frac{2}{1}=2\end{equation*}

---

the reason you are wrong is because when you divide by $x^2$ you get $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4 + x^2} + x}{x^2 \sin (\frac{1}{x})}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac4{x^4} + \frac1{x^2}} + \frac1x}{\sin (\frac{1}{x})}=\frac{0}{0}$$this is an indeterminate form, and not equal $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{x\sin(1/x)}=1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{4+x^{2}}+x}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{x^{2}}+1}+1=2$.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to take into account when finding this limit. First of all, recall that $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1}$. Secondly, if $\theta=\frac{1}{x}$ and $x\rightarrow \infty$, then $\theta\rightarrow 0$. And thirdly, we're going to use this simple fact $\lim_\limits{\theta \rightarrow 0}\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}=1$. Here's the entire solution:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4 + x^2} + x}{x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}}
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt{4 + x^2} + x}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{x\sin \frac{1}{x}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left[\left(\frac{\sqrt{4 + x^2}}{x}+\frac{x}{x}\right)\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\sin \frac{1}{x}}\right]\\
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt{4 + x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2}}+1\right)\cdot \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\sin \frac{1}{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\sqrt{\frac{4}{x^2} + 1}+1\right)\cdot \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0}\frac{\theta}{\sin \theta}\\
&=\left(\sqrt{0 + 1}+1\right)\cdot 1\\
&=\left(1+1\right)\cdot 1\\
&=2
\end{align}

---

Now, let's actually prove $\lim_\limits{\theta \rightarrow 0}\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}=1$ because I don't like to leave things unjustified. And  I sure hope that you remember one of the most fundamental trigonometric limits in elementary calculus $\lim_\limits{\theta \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$ (proof is [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-derivative-rules/ab-derivtive-rules-opt-vids/v/sinx-over-x-as-x-approaches-0)):

$$
\lim_\limits{\theta \rightarrow 0}\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}=
\lim_\limits{\theta \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}}=
\frac{\lim_\limits{\theta \rightarrow 0} 1}{\lim_\limits{\theta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}}=\frac{1}{1}=1
$$